# Android Gallery Jumps when swiped quickly or slowly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I've made an activity that looks a lot like the level select screen from angry birds: there is a grid of button, and you can scroll through pages of them by swiping right or left. 
I built it by creating a layout of the buttons, and then adding those layout to a Gallery view. 
**The problem is** the animation is jerky, even if you swipe extra slowly, the content jumps ahead. Even when you fling the gallery page, it skips and jumps along its way to its destination.

I am wondering how to fix this: Maybe the complex layout it making it non responsive during the inflate?

Do you know how to fix this, or of a good way to do a workaround using some other approach that will let me have 3 or more screens smoothly swiping from page to page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using ViewPager. This is available in android support packages. Gallery Widget will not be smooth if you add components into it which has a lot of touch actions.
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html